# Why does this sscanf example code output something wrong?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[] = "e:a";
  unsigned char c[2] = {0,};
  sscanf(a,"%1x:%1x",&c[0],&c[1]);
  printf("%d\n", c[0]);
  printf("%d\n", c[1]);
}
```

I expect output of this code,

```
14
10
```

But,

```
14
0
```

However, when I corrected code like below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[] = "e1:1a";
  unsigned char c[2] = {0,};
  sscanf(a,"%2x:%2x",&c[0],&c[1]);
  printf("%d\n", c[0]);
  printf("%d\n", c[1]);
}
```

The output is,

```
30
26
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong is that you need to compile your code with warnings enabled.

Comment: You might want to check e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Look up the `"%x"` format in the table and check the possible prefixes.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to an `unsigned int` when using a `%x` format in sscanf.  Since you instead passed pointers to `unsigned char`, you are writing past `c` and corrupting memory.  The behavior is, of course, undefined.

Comment: And yes, please be sure to fix all of your warnings before posting here.  If you don't know how, then that should be the subject of your post.

Comment: On my system , both examples work as they should ( second outputs 225 , 26) , besides the warning of trying to put 32bit(or whatever int is on your system) on 8bits , if the numbers are <256 it should be ok...

Comment: @Alexie No.  The magnitude of the numbers doesn't matter.  `sscanf` will write to the *entire* `unsigned int` even if the value is, say, zero.  It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, it is but on a little-endian system the first byte would be intact and that would be stored on the char address , I'm thinking that's why it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Mis-match `scanf()` type and argument. [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837450/why-does-this-sscanf-example-code-output-something-wrong#comment57416161_34837450)

```
// bad
unsigned char c[2] = {0,};
sscanf(a,"%1x:%1x",&c[0],&c[1]);
```

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined C11dr §7.21.6.2 13

Either use `unsigned *` with `"%x"` or use `unsigned char *` with `"%hhx"`.

```
unsigned c[2];
sscanf(a,"%1x:%1x",&c[0],&c[1]);
// or
unsigned char c[2];
sscanf(a,"%1hhx:%1hhx",&c[0],&c[1]);
```

Good compilers with their warnings enabled typically report this problem - saves time.

---

Good to check `sscanf()` results.

```
if (sscanf(a,"%1x:%1x",&c[0],&c[1]) != 2) Handle_ScanFailure.
```